# HTTP Post with request body failed when using Regex to validate body parameter

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I'm testing an Express API using the post method.

The request body is like

```
{
    "menuId": "id2-test",
    "menuName": "test menu name 2",
    "menuUrl": "/admin/menu/test",
    "desc": "this is test menu 2 description",
    "menuOrder": 2,
    "usageStatus": "true" 
}
```

As you could see there is a property `menuUrl` which is a path of a valid URL. So to make sure user can enter the valid value for all provided properties. I've tried to validate the menuUrl using `Regex`

```
router.post(
  "/",
  validate(paramValidation.createMenu),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userInfo } = req;
    const menu = new Menus({
      menuUrl: req.body.menuUrl,
      ...req.body,
    });

    // Regex validation is here
    if (!menu?.menuUrl.match(/^[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*:/)) {
      return new ApiError("MENU_URL_NOT_VALID", httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, true);
    }

    menu.createdBy = userInfo.userNm;

    await Menus.findOne({ menuId: menu.menuId })
      .then((_menu) => {
        if (!_menu) {
          return menu.save();
        }
        const err = new ApiError("ROLE_ALREADY", httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, true);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      })
      .then((_menu) => {
        res.status(httpStatus.CREATED).json(_menu);
        return null;
      })
      .catch((e) => next(e));
  }
);
```

However, When the request is made, I received the error that said that `could not get response`. If I remove the Regex validation step above, and then everything still working fine. What happened with that?

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern you seem to want here is something like:

```regex
^/[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*(?:/[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*)*$
```

Updated code:

```js
if (!menu?.menuUrl.match(/^\/[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*(?:\/[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*)*$/)) {
    return new ApiError("MENU_URL_NOT_VALID", httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, true);
}
```

Comment: @Thanks for the comment, However using your code, it is just possible to make request with a valid `menuUrl`. When I tried inserting an invalid `menuUrl`, the above error still occurs.